# Create python TcpSocketServer from existing socket

Tags: python, sockets, socketserver

Suppose I have an existing socket, say that is passed in as a file descriptor from systemd socket activation. How would I use the [socketserver](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html) module to create a `socketserver.TcpServer` or `socketserver.UnixStreamServer` that utilizes the existing socket instead of listening on a new one?

Comment: It doesn't look like you can do it with that module. The basic `socket` module has `socket.fromfd()`.